# How can I use Mono.Cecil to call a generic method

Tags: il, mono.cecil

I'm trying to import a method and its IL code like
`callvirt   instance !!0 [UnityEngine]UnityEngine.GameObject::AddComponent<class RealMono>()`
The `RealMono` is a `MonoBehavior` which I created .
I have no idea to get the generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!!

```
using System.Reflection;

...

MemberInfo[] ms = typeof(GameObject).GetMember("AddComponent*", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
MethodInfo mm = null;
foreach(MemberInfo m in ms) {
    if (((MethodInfo)m).IsGenericMethod) {
        mm = (MethodInfo)m;
        mm = mm.MakeGenericMethod(mm);
        break;
    }
}
il.InsertBefore(method.Body.Instructions[0], il.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, assembly.MainModule.Import(mm)));
```